# How to call toHaveBeenCalledWith with multiple parameters?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Hi I am developing web application in `Angular JS`. I am writing unit test cases using `Jasmine` framework. I am trying to mock some services. I am not able to call service with multiple parameters. Below is my unit test code.

```
it('update is allowed false', async(() => {
        let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserOnboardEndpointMock);
        spyOn(service, 'updateUser').and.callThrough();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(service.updateUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(true,"101"));
        })
    }));
```

Below is my service.

```
 updateUser<T>(event: boolean, userid: string): Observable<T>{
        var updateUserResult = { result: true } as any;
        return Observable.of<T>(updateUserResult);
    }
```

I have tried as below to call service but nothing worked out.

```
expect(service.updateUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true,"101");
expect(service.updateUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith([true]["101"]);
```

Can someone help me to call my mock services? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Since jest 23.0 there is .toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(nthCall, arg1, arg2, ....) https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeennthcalledwithnthcall-arg1-arg2-

So you could make an assertion like:
`expect(service.updateUser).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, true,"101");`